# UIPickerView scrolling rows disappear

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I've searched but I haven't found a solution to this, I have a UIPickerView and when I start view works fine, when I scrolling rows disappear

```
class SemanaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let letters = ["A","B","C","D","F","G","H"]

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
        self.pickerView.delegate = self
        ....
    }
....
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return letters.count
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return letters[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        //pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        pickerLabel.text = letters[row]

        return pickerLabel
    }
```

Prints

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Reloading Picker anywhere ?

Comment: @McDonal_11, i dont reloading

Comment: @MarcusMenezes did you implemented `viewForRow: forComponent` method for `UIPickerViewDelegate`.

Comment: @Rocky Yes, same error

Comment: @MarcusMenezes share code for that method also.

Comment: @Rocky Done! update on post

Comment: @MarcusMenezes set frame for `UILabel` in method `viewForRow: forComponent`.

Comment: @Rocky thanks for your help, but I could not solve and I create a alternative, the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I identified that the error was happening according to the way I was creating the views.

I have a UISegmentedControl and 2 subviews(UIViewController) and the error happened 1 subview(SemanalmenteViewController),  I've changed how subviews are created this work's.

I dont know but I think it has to do with the Parent View Controller.